# tkinter dialog window not working inside while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop, menu

Apparently, tkinter doesn't allow you to use a while loop as it already runs its own loop so I need help on making my code work with the while loop. I believe it has something to do with "mainloop()" but I'm not sure how to use it.

Code below (works without loop):

```
while (1):
    choice = input("Choose 1 to open dialog, 2 to end the program.\n")
    if choice == "1":
        from tkinter import *
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ([("Text file","*.txt")]),title='Please select a text file')
        file = open(fileName)
        sentence = file.read()
        file.close()

    elif choice == "2":
        break
```

Comment: Why are you writing a GUI that uses `input`?  Is your program a GUI, or a command line tool that needs to pop up a dialog?

Comment: It is a command line tool that needs to pop up a dialog

Comment: You don't need all of that compress and uncompress code just to illustrate the problem with opening a dialog in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've witdrawn the window with `root.witdraw()` all the code associated with the `root` will not run, so you need to keep the window open while the user is opening dialog

You could stick a `label` on the window saying "Choose some dialogue to open", or as Bryan Oakley said you could use either command line or graphical interface

```
choice = ""
while choice != "2": # no need for brackets here
    choice = input("Choose 1 to open dialog, 2 to end the program.\n")
    if choice == "1":
        from tkinter import *
        root = Tk()
        root.title("Choose dialog")
        #root.withdraw() this causes the problem
        fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ([("Text file","*.txt")]),title='Please select a text file')
        if fileName != "": # if they choose not to open a file
            file = open(fileName)
            sentence = file.read()
            print(sentence)
            file.close()
            root.destroy() # destroys the window
```

I've tested it and this does work, hope this helps you